no muestra el resultado correcto, nodejs
por una parte tengo una parte del codigo que crear una promesa
const saludaNombre = (nombre) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve("hola ${nombre}");
    })
}
module.exports={saludaNombre}

y por otra la que debe de coger los datos para mostralos
const { saludaNombre } = require("./modulo");

saludaNombre("alberto")
.then(r=>console.log(r))
.catch(e=>console.log(e))

al ejecutar node app.js en vez de mostrarme "hola alberto me muestra hola ${nombre}

Los string template se definen con tildes invertidas, es decir, `, no "

De acuerdo con @Benito-B

Puede que hayas confundido las comillas
const saludaNombre = (nombre) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(`hola ${nombre}`);
    })
}
module.exports={saludaNombre}

Te recomiendo leer Using promises, A guide to promises in Node.js y Promises in Node.js para que veas buenas practicas sobre el manejo de las promesas, aunque en tu caso creo que es un error de codificación más que del lenguaje en si.
Intenta de esta manera y me dices, saludos.

No le encuentro sentido a hacer resolve("hola " + ${nombre});. Por qué ${nombre}?? Qué intentas conseguir con eso? No se usa interpolación cuando no estás dentro de un string template. Al hacer "Hola " + nombre ya estás usando lenguaje JS puramente, es una concatenación de dos objetos de tipo string. Intentar usar ${} no es ni siquiera código JS válido fuera del string template

Por q es para q pueda mostrar cualquier valor que recibe nombre

Ochoa ,era eso , como algunos lenguajes permite " me llevo a confusión,gracias
